# Array Length Initialized with Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am trying to have a user input an `int` and then input that number of names.

The program prints those names backwards and in reverse order. However, the array where I am storing these names is always being created one element too small when I use `Scanner`. When I just assign a number myself, I don't have this problem. Is there something unique with `Scanner` or what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class forTester {
    public static void main (String str[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 

        //Why does this commented code scan only one less name than expected???
        /*
        System.out.println("How many names do you want to enter?");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter " + num + " Names:");
        String names[] = new String[num];
        */ 
        //Comment out the next two lines if you use the four lines above.
        System.out.println("Enter " + 4 + " Names:");
        String names[] = new String[4];

        // The code below works fine.
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            names[i]=scan.nextLine(); 
        }

        for(int i = names.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for(int p = names[i].length() - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
                System.out.print(names[i].charAt(p));
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change commented code to :

```
   System.out.println("How many names do you want to enter?");
   int num = scan.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter " + num + " Names:");
   String names[] = new String[num];
   scan.nextLine(); // added this to consume the end of the line that contained
                    // the first number you read
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `nextInt()` leaves behind a new line character which will be gobbled by the `nextLine()` in the first iteration. So, you feel that the array size is one less. Actually, your first element of the array i.e, 0th index will have a new line character.

Your code should be :

```
  System.out.println("How many names do you want to enter?");
   int num = scan.nextInt(); // leaves behind a new line character
   System.out.println("Enter " + num + " Names:");
   String names[] = new String[num];
   scan.nextLine() // to read the new line character left behind by scan.nextInt()
```